# App Inspection not found in Android Studio Giraffe

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

Working on a Flutter project, I can't find the app inspection option in Android Studio, it is not found on view -> tool windows

Android Studio version: Giraffe 2022.3.1

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/assets/images/docs/tools/devtools/inspector_screenshot.png)?

Comment: No, App Inspection for SQLite databases

Answer (score 1):

Im experiencing the same issue and ive filed a bug report for it to google, also referencing this post. Ive tried to find a workaround for this issue and found none. I note that the database inspector is still showing in my settings menu with one single 'offline mode' option

I can also see app inspection was supposed to have had a fix implemented under 2022.3.1 for database inspection icon problems, but no other issues are listed for database inspection, making me file this as a bug. [2022.3.1 release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/fixed-bugs/studio/2022.3.1)

Answer (score -1):

You can find app inspection as follow in Giraffe 2022.3.1

> View -> Tool Windows -> App Inspection

Comment: I included a screenshot in my question, it's not there

Comment: are you able to find from search from help -> find action ?

Comment: No, nothing appears